# Objective C NSURLConnection dosen't get response data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection

I am creating this application, it communicates with a PHP script on my web-server.

Last night it was working perfectly. But today two of the connections does not get response.

I've tried the NSURL link in my browser, it works fine. Also one of the connections work, but as i said two connections does not work?

```
- (void) getVitsTitelByID:(int)id {

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://webserver.com   /ivitserdk.php?function=gettitelbyid&id=%d", id];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:1.0];
connectionTitelByID = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

connectionDidReciveData:

```
if(connection == connectionTitelByID){
    responseTitel = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

connectionDidFinishLoading:

```
if(connection == connectionTitelByID){
    titelLabel.text = responseTitel;
}
```

I've tried and debugging it.

responseTitel seems to be (null).

Help would be apriceated :)

Comment: Is `data` also null in `connectionDidReceiveData`?

Comment: Data is is null, and URL is the valid link.

Comment: I already explain that the response does not get set for some reason.?

Comment: see my answer you have to cope with X calls to didReceive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didReceiveData may be called N (**several**) times. save the data to a mutably data buffer (queue it up) and in didFinish read it into a string

mock code:

```
- (void) getVitsTitelByID:(int)identifier {
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://webserver.com/ivitserdk.php?function=gettitelbyid&id=%d", identifier];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:1.0];
    connectionTitelByID = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    dataForConnectionTitelByID = [NSMutableData data];
    [connectionTitelByID start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if(!data.length) return;

    if(connection == connectionTitelByID)
        [dataForConnectionTitelByID appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    if(connection == connectionTitelByID) {
        id str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataForConnectionTitelByID encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
        dataForConnectionTitelByID = nil;
        connectionTitelByID = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if i have multiple connections?

Comment: do your if inside and have serveral buffers.. if(connection1) [connection1Data appendData] else if(connection2) [connection2Data appendData] ...

Comment: (not an answer but . you should really consider either AFNetworking or NSURLConns new block syntax]

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7566220 i get that error when i try and run?

Comment: its mock code, I typed it inline it isnt meant to compile even. :) it should only further underline the way you have to deal with the didReceive method called N times

Comment: Still giving me a crash for unrecognized selector

Comment: Yes, i ARC is enabled in my project.

Comment: It says [_NSArrayM appendData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: ah yes so THAT  I know . blush edited and fixed, mutableArray => mutableData

Comment: Haha. Okay all worked now, but i just found out the problem is that when there is æøå in the return data it wont accept it? How would i fix that? :)